# Java 8 Stream as data source for Spring Batch ItemReader

Tags: spring, java-8, stream, reader

I would like to use a `Java 8` Stream as a data source for a *Spring Batch* `ItemReader`.

Is there any way to do this?

I am currently using **Spring Batch 3.0.7**.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a stream as resultType you can also return an IteratorItemReader:

```
Stream<BigDecimal> stream  = repository.getStream();

return new IteratorItemReader<>(stream.iterator());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an adapter method like

```
public static <T> ItemReader<T> itemReader(BaseStream<? extends T,?> stream) {
    Spliterator<? extends T> source = stream.spliterator();
    List<T> container = new ArrayList<>(1);
    return () -> source.tryAdvance(container::add)? container.remove(0): null;
}
```

which also handles primitive streams, e.g.

```
for(ItemReader<Integer> r = itemReader(IntStream.range(0, 10));;) {
    Integer i = r.read();
    if(i == null) break;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

But care must be taken not to have `null` elements in the stream when using a reference type stream, as `null` references returned by the `ItemReader` are interpreted as end marker.

An alternative is to throw an exception when encountering a `null` reference in the stream:

```
public static <T> ItemReader<T> itemReader(BaseStream<? extends T,?> stream) {
    Spliterator<? extends T> source = stream.spliterator();
    List<T> container = new ArrayList<>(1);
    if(source.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.NONNULL))
        return () -> source.tryAdvance(container::add)? container.remove(0): null;
    else
        return () -> source.tryAdvance(container::add)?
                     Objects.requireNonNull(container.remove(0)): null;
}
```